# setting up credentials for Oauth failed. Resource invalid

Tags: oauth-2.0, oauth, google-ads-api

I am attempting to follow several guides to implement a API access to our own google ads api. The goal is to load spend and campaign information to our internal data warehouse so we can build reports etc.. Pretty straight forward. oh no!

We use a SaaS tool called Celigo to build interfaces to API's in this case the google API. I have followed the guides, which have not been simple for me to understand:)

After several failed attempt, I finally thought I was on the right lines, I enabled the API in GOOGLE CLOUD under my project. set up a OAuth consent screen.
I then attempted to create credentials.
however I get this internal error to which after much google-ing I can't find any support for. Does anybody have any experience of this issue? or help my unblock this part ?  thanks in hope!

[The request failed because one of the field of the resource is invalid.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5th9y.png)

Expecting to create oauth credentials

FYI guides I have been following are
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HXKpfGqPRy0&t=1042s
https://docs.celigo.com/hc/en-us/articles/360060770192-Set-up-a-connection-to-Google-Ads#Client-Info3

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.